# Is it possible to point to multiple Hadoop clusters at a time from Greenplum using GPHDFS?

Tags: hdfs, greenplum

We have a Greenplum environment and currently we have configured gphdfs to enable data writing on HDFS from Greenplum. There is a requirement to write to a different HDFS for a different user. Is it possible to configure different gphdfs configurations for different users, so that depending on the user, the data is written on its corresponding configured HDFS?

Expected Outcome:
From User 1, when I create WRITABLE EXTERNAL table, the Location attribute would look like, 
LOCATION ( ‘gphdfs://hdfs_1_for_user1:8020/path/’)

From User 2, when I create WRITABLE EXTERNAL table, the Location attribute would look like,
LOCATION ( ‘gphdfs://hdfs_2_for_user2:8020/path/’)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on version 5+ of Greenplum, you can use PXF to access Hadoop clusters. In PXF, you can create different server configurations such that each user can access a different HDFS cluster.

For example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table_on_hdfs_cluster_1 (...) 
LOCATION('pxf://my/path/on/hdfs/cluster/1?PROFILE=hdfs:text&SERVER=hdfs1')
FORMAT 'TEXT';
```

and for the second cluster:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table_on_hdfs_cluster_2 (...) 
LOCATION('pxf://my/path/on/hdfs/cluster/2?PROFILE=hdfs:text&SERVER=hdfs2')
FORMAT 'TEXT';
```

However, you would need different external tables to access each HDFS cluster.

You can find additional information for PXF here: https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5180/pxf/access_hdfs.html

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that gphdfs is deprecated in Greenplum 6.

Comment: Thank you Frank, PXF would be helpful.